# What's a word for having your identity stolen?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for having your identity stolen?

In other words, "robbed" is to your stuff as *X* is to your identity.

Comment: Still robbed or stolen. We don't seem to have come up with something new. Law enforcement uses identity *theft*.

Comment: Maybe cyberjacked?

Comment: Just because English has words for everything doesn’t mean it has a single word for everything, nor need it have such.

Comment: "Help, I've been selfnapped!"

Answer (score 2):

[Identity theft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theft) is the term used for this phenomenon.

Your identity is *stolen* by identity thieves.

Here is a link to the Federal Trade Commission's site on [Identity Theft](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/features/feature-0014-identity-theft).  It explains many of the different types of identity theft.

Most identity theft is done with the intent of impersonation for financial gain.  Opening credit cards, etc.

So, you can also call this crime [*fraud*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraud).

Comment: And because the thieves use the postal service to receive their cards, it is also [mail and wire fraud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_fraud).

Answer (score 1):

`Hijacked` -

> Someone hijacked my identity.

`Hacked` could also work.

Answer (score -1):

Although not featuring in any official dictionary, *identitheft* is becoming increasingly popular.

Edit: 'Just because English has words for everything doesn’t mean it has a single word for everything, nor need it have such. –  tchrist'. I agree, but it could also be said that English is what it is today through its use of other languages and continual adaptation.